# Magento home page session issue with Venus Theme Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7

My session is lost on home page. Its working fine on all other pages, including all cms pages. Cart gets empty and customer information is not shown.

However, when I go away from home page, cart is repopulated.

If I click on preview link of home page inside CMS -> Pages it works fine there.

I am unable to resolve the issue.

What could be the reason? Any suggestions/tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found the main suspect for my issue. The following observer in ProductList module of Venus theme somehow breaks the functionality of session on home page.

```
<controller_front_init_routers>
     <observers>
        <ves_produlist_observer>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Ves_ProductList_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>initControllerRouters</method>
        </ves_produlist_observer>
     </observers>
</controller_front_init_routers>
```

I am still finding out the actual reason but for those who are effected by the same issue, temporary solution is to disable that observer.

Thank you